# I can't use jai-imageio / jai-imageio-jpeg2000

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jpeg2000

I am trying to use the community fork of the original java.net project jai-imageio-core (which is no longer available upstream), and use it to write jpeg2000 images. The fork for the core imageIO project is available at: [here](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core)

And the jpeg2000 spi is at: [here](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000)

I am just trying to run one of the simplest tests for the jpeg2000 spi:

```
    IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
    registry.registerServiceProvider(new com.github.jaiimageio.jpeg2000.impl.J2KImageReaderSpi());
    
    String[] suff = ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes();
    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jp2");
```

But it does not find any ImageWriter which can handle this jp2 extension. However, it is correctly defined in the `J2KImageReaderSpi`class.

What I detected is that the JVM (I'm using Java 8) does not use the fork for imageio but the JDK default imageio version. Which might be the reaosn for my problem. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> registry.registerServiceProvider(new J2KImageReaderSpi());
> ```
>
> What did I do wrong?

You were registering the `J2KImageReaderSpi` (*Reader*), while you are were looking for the `J2KWriter` (*Writer*).

If you want to write JPEG2000, try registering the `J2KImageWriterSpi` instead:

```
registry.registerServiceProvider(new J2KImageWriterSpi());
```

Although I think this should just happen automatically if the JARs contain the correct `META-INF/services` entries, and you place the JAR on the class path.